# How to access a view's dimensions from an Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

Accessing `myView.getWidth()` and `getHeight()` always return zero, and I understand this is because I'm calling them too early, before the views have been laid out.

But how CAN I access the size of views from an activity? I can't see a method to override and the docs aren't suggesting a `lifecycle` event I can catch.

===================================

Thanks Tanner. Here's the code I used, which works fine.

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
Display d = ((WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidth = d.getWidth();
int screenHeight = d.getHeight();
root.measure(screenWidth, screenHeight);
View myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
int width = myView.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Have you tried calling `measure()` and then `getMeasuredWidth()` on your view?

Notice there is also the method `requestLayout()`

Comment: This looks like what I need, though measure() needs parent width and height passed to it, so best approach to get screen width and height then pass those to measure() to measure the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

You should access dimensins after your layout was set as content view of activity. 
Just find it by id using findViewById(id) and then call myView.getWidth()